# How to power EATX12v 6 pin connector

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

I'm having trouble figuring out if and how I need to power the EATX12V_3 power slot on my Asus WS z390 Pro ([Manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Ki3.png)). I've read that the EATX12V_3 connector is used to provide extra power to the x16 PCIe lanes. Would my system (NVLINK 2080ti's) benefit from having that connector powered?

If so, the issue is that power connector is an EATX12V 6 pin connector, but I cannot find an 6 pin ATX power cable (all of the provided PSU ATX cables split into 4+4 pins, not 6+2, and I cannot find such a connector online). I've read that the PCIe 6 pin power connectors provide the same voltages but in different polarities. Is that an issue?

Build:

- CPU: Intel Core i9-9900KF 3.6 GHz 8-Core Processor
- CPU Cooler: be quiet! Dark Rock Pro 4 50.5 CFM CPU Cooler
- Memory: Corsair Vengeance LPX 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3000 Memory
- Memory: Corsair Vengeance LPX 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3000 Memory
- Motherboard: ASUS WS Z390 Pro
- Storage: Samsung 970 Evo 1 TB M.2-2280 Solid State Drive
- Video Card: EVGA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti 11 GB Black Video Card
- Video Card: EVGA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti 11 GB Black Video Card
- Case: Cooler Master MasterCase H500 ATX Mid Tower Case
- Power Supply: Corsair HX Platinum 1000i W 80+ Platinum Certified Fully Modular ATX Power Supply